# Photo Competition 2021-11-01: No Landscapes

Tags: photo-competition

### Theme: No Landscapes

As many of the photos have been landscapes, I think we should try to encourage photos that are not landscapes and more macro, portraits etc.

This theme was suggested by [damned truths](//photo.stackexchange.com/users/10405/damned-truths).

#### Voting Rules

- View the submissions [sorted by active](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/126574/photo-competition-2021-10-18-no-landscapes?answertab=active#tab-top) to give every submitter a fair chance
- Vote up as many images as you like
- Please, **up votes only!** Do NOT vote down your competitors! If you don't like an image, don't vote
- **Voting closes on November 15, 2021 at 12:01 AM UTC** (00:01 UTC if you prefer a 24-hour time). The winner will be chosen based on votes at that time.

#### Submission Rules

1. One photo submission per answer. Up to three (3) entries allowed.
2. Post only photos taken by yourself or the person with you.
3. **All entries should include:**

   - a **title** for the photo
   - a **location and date**, if known
   - **camera, lens, and exposure settings**, if known
   - any other explanatory notes, comments, etc., that you want to include (completely optional)
4. The submitted image must conform to this site's content license, Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 ([CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)) with [attribution required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/).
5. Do not use this as a forum for photo critique. Use [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=photo.stackexchange.com) instead, or [ask a new question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) about your image.

---

#### Next Contest

Suggest a theme by writing a new answer at the [Photo of the Week Theme Ideas](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1740/) thread. Please make sure to check the [PotW theme ideas Archive](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1741/) first, to make sure you aren't recycling a theme.

The highest-voted theme will be the next theme.

Good luck!

Comment: At what point do we decide that recycling a theme might be preferable to trying to come up with a poorly defined theme that hasn't been used because it's not a good theme?

Comment: @MichaelC That's a good question. Honestly, I don't think it's a _bad_ theme, but that it's of the time it was suggested. That is, it seemed to be a reaction to many of the photos or themes suggested 9 or so years ago. Right now, I'm just pulling off the top voted from the theme list. I suppose I could call an audible and skip a theme, or just make up my own. But I'm hesitant to do so, because people wanted some heads up to prepare for a particular theme.

Comment: Certainly not bad, but perhaps a bit over-broad. I think generally speaking, inclusive themes produce a more robust comparison than exclusive themes. "Red Cars" encompasses 10.3% of cars, so "Not Red Cars" is a much broader field.

Comment: By the same token, though, it's a lot harder to compare a nature photo of a hawk to a studio photo of a human dressed as an angel. There's practically nothing in common between the two with which to compare them, other than the fact they're both photos. "Cars that are not red" would still be a limited enough category to allow more direct comparison. "Not red cars" can include a photo of the moon, a photo of a printed circuit board, and a photo of a reclining female figure.

Comment: I mean, at that point what is the purpose of having a category at all?

Comment: @scottbb Where can we find information about how the "Theme" is currently selected?

Comment: @MichaelC at the [Photo of the Week Theme Ideas](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1740/) thread, linked to from the bottom of every contest page (under "Next Contest")

Comment: @MichaelC Fair, I see how you could read my comment that way. I wasn't suggesting it as a theme, I was thinking more in terms of sending someone out to parking lot to look for a specific car.

Comment: To add insult to injury, under the largest umbrella defining what a "landscape" photo is, over half the current entries below are, in fact, landscape photos.

Comment: @MichaelC I think the definition of 'Landscape' is hazy enough that you'll need to supply what you think is an acceptable description.  I'm not sure going down the entries and pasting "Many definitions of "landscape" would include this" is either helpful or encouraging.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Sherwood Toadstool**
Amanita muscaria

[image: Sherwood Toadstool]

Sherwood Forest, UK
October 17 2021
Fujifilm X-T3, XF35mm
f/2.8, 1/500, ISO 500

Answer (score 8):

**Stainless Shadows**

[image: Stainless Shadows]

Fujifilm X-E3, XF18-55mm @55mm
1/150 at f/5.6, ISO 200

Detail, Jay Pritzker Pavilion, Millennium Park, Chicago.
Frank Gehry, Architect.

Answer (score 6):

**Are you next?**
A red tailed hawk eating a small mammal
[image]
Canon M6 Mk II, 100-400 Mk I at 400mm plus 1.4x extender
f/9, 1/1000, ISO 1600
Wavecrest, Half Moon Bay, CA, USA
October 25, 2021, morning
A red-tailed hawk that was on the ground next to my path.  When I came around a corner 15 feet from it we were both surprised.  It was eating a mouse or vole it had caught.  I got one shot (2 stops overexposed) before it flew up into this tree.

Comment: What is the plant on which the bird is sitting? Just interested!

Comment: @CoolCoder:   I believe it is a Monterey Cypress

Comment: Thank You so much!

Answer (score 6):

### Basil Addict

[image]

Los Gatos CA, July 23 2021

Nikon D500 with Sigma 150-600

f/6.3, 1/2500, ISO800

Answer (score 5):

**Morning lotus**

[image: Morning lotus]

Fujifilm X-E3, XF55-200mm @150mm
1/250 at f/8.0, ISO 200

Chicago Botanic Gardens, Glencoe, IL 8/4/2021

Answer (score 5):

**Morning Dew**

[image: Morning Dew]

Zoom in for detail...

Fujifilm X-T3, XF80mm Macro
1/170 at f/4.0, ISO 80
Focus stacked, 30 frames

Chicago Botanic Gardens, Glencoe, IL 9/29/2021

Answer (score 4):

**Fun With a Baby Rattler**

[image]

Nikon D7000, Tokina 100mm, f/16, 1/200, ISO 125, one studio strobe w/ umbrella & reflector card.
Working distance: approximately 13cm.
24 September 2016

Young Western diamondback rattlesnake (pit viper). Coiled up like it is, it will fit in the palm of your hand - so cute! This snake coiled up on the same window sill (window sill is at ground level) for a few nights. Baby rattlers are fairly docile, but if they do bite you they have little control over their venom injection (not good). A puff of air makes the snake flicker its tongue. In spite of me flashing and puffing air at the snake, it didn't move for the 60 minute photo session.

Answer (score 4):

### Yum

Cooper's hawk eating a western blue scrub jay.

[image]

Los Gatos CA, Sept 25 2021

Nikon D500 with Sigma 150-600

f/6.3, 1/1000, ISO14368

Answer (score 3):

**Moonset**

[image]

A full moon setting into 30 Hudson Yards. (#6 of a sequence of 10)
June 8, 2020
Canon EOS 6D, 100-300mm @ 290mm, f/7.1, 1/400 second, ISO 100

This used to be the view from our apartment window, but after I took this a newer skyscraper topped out and blocked most of this.

Answer (score 3):

**Echo**

[image]

Jaume Plensa’s *Echo* sculpture [in New York City's Madison Square Park on May 7, 2011](https://madisonsquarepark.org/art/exhibitions/jaume-plensa-echo/).  Zooming while the shutter was open.

Canon EOS 400D, 24-85mm zoom, f/22, 1/40 second.

Answer (score 3):

**Evening sun setting between buildings**

[image]

Nikon D5600
1/100 sec, f/8 , 55 mm
ISO 100

Time : 1649 hours

Answer (score 2):

### Standoff

[image]

CA, June 13 2021

Nikon D500 with Sigma 150-600

f/10, 1/800, ISO635